# Applying CSS for mutiple id is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply width for my divisions using jquery. The following code is working fine for me.

```
$('#bodycontainer').css('width','300px'); 
$('#footer').css('width','300px');
```

But when combine both id's and keep it as a single rule is not working. see below.

```
$('#bodycontainer','#footer').css('width','300px');
```

What i am doing wrong here??

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RUmYb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this way:

```
$('#bodycontainer, #footer').css('width','300px');
```

Here you have selected multiple selectors with `,` separated in a single string.

---

### Issue with your code:

```
$('#bodycontainer','#footer')
```

Using this way is says that find me `#bodycontainer` in `#footer`. The second one is treated as a context.

#### [Prooved](http://jsfiddle.net/H6ML9/)

so what that mean is this:

```
$('#bodycontainer','#footer') === $('#footer').find('#bodycontainer')
```

Both are equal to this.

Comment: Its okay @SureshPonnukalai, I hope this helped you understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The way you have used the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) is wrong

Try,

```
$('#bodycontainer,#footer').css('width','300px');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RUmYb/3/)

Comment: Please don't use code spans (`like this`) for phrases like "multiple selector", they are only meant for code within sentences.